# Array into table in Python

Tags: python, arrays, hashtable

So I converted a CSV that has names in one column and values in the second column into two arrays, one array for the name and one array for the values. I want to convert this into a table that equates the two, so the first item in the name array is linked to the first item in the value. How do I go about doing this?

```
import csv

data = csv.reader(open('C:\\Users\\Grant\\Documents\\finalproject\\centers.csv', 'r'), delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
names, values = [], []

for row in data:
    names.append(row[0])
    values.append(row[1])
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: I've tried to turn it into a dictionary, using dict(zip(column1, zip(*column2))) but when i try and return the dictionary, nothing shows up, so i'm not sure if that is working. this is my code thus far                                          import csv

data = csv.reader(open('C:\\Users\\Grant\\Documents\\finalproject\\centers.csv', 'r'), delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
column1, column2 = [], []

for row in data:
    column1.append(row[0])
    column2.append(row[1])

centers = dict(zip(column1, zip(*column2)))
print(centers)

Comment: Help us help you - share the code you have so far

Comment: sorry, just now edited the comment with my code

Comment: comments don't format well for code, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47611988/edit) your question and put code in there, highlight the code and press `{}` to format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names = ["a", "b", "c"]
values = [1, 2, 3]
for n, v in zip(names, values):
    print("{} = {}".format(n, v))
```

Comment: Ah this is what I was looking for. Thank you! sorry for my poor asking of the question, i'm super new to the site and coding in general

Comment: Don't worry about it. Everyone has to start somehow :). (Would you mind accepting my answer as correct? ^^)

Answer (score 2):

Since you say `table` I would suggest you go with dataframes by pandas.

Assuming your name list to be `names` and value list to be `values`,

You could have something like:

```
data = {'names': names, 'values': values}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Of course you have to `import pandas` first.

Which will give you a *"table"* (or dataframe?) like:

```
         names          values
0      Byakuya           500
1     Kenpachi           600
2          Kon           50
```

*Further read* [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).